# How to programatically add secure_path in sudoers file

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to build a user data script for an EC2 instance that builds node and npm from github, and then starts a service. To grease these wheels, I need to add:

```
:/usr/local/bin
```

to the end of the line in /etc/sudoers which starts:

```
Defaults        secure_path="
```

https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands talks about using visudo to achieve this, but I want to do it programatically within the EC2 user data.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282789/adding-sudo-permissions-to-sudoers-for-user-via-shell-script talks about editing the sudoers file, but it seems awfully over baked for what I'm trying to achieve.

I thought it'd be easy to grep the line and replace it, but I'm stumped. Not only because of that annoying closing inverted comma!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can live with replacing the `secure_path` value instead of appending it, you can use a much easier solution. Usually sudo has a config directory like `/etc/sudoers.d` where you can drop additional configuration files.

Just create a file there with your complete `secure_path` value:

```
Defaults secure_path="<default value>:/usr/local/bin"
```

This overwrites the value from the main config. If the path value is the same for all your machines this can easily be deployed with scripts or a package.

This has the additional advantage that you don't have to check and possibly merge config files when the sudo package is updated in the future.

Answer (score 4):

assuming you know the line with secure_path exists, a simple sed command to do this

```
sed -i -e '/secure_path/ s[=.*[&:/usr/local/bin[' /etc/sudoers
```

or a bit more sophisticated (more syntax check on input) :

```
sed -i -r -e '/^\s*Defaults\s+secure_path/ s[=(.*)[=\1:/usr/local/bin[' /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Thank you!  The second line was a really clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Lately, (perhaps since ever) you could've just added a line like this:

```
Defaults secure_path += ":/usr/local/bin"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with secure_path